# UPDATE with ADO in Access VBA Array

Tags: vba

I have 31 text boxes that get populated with ADO from a Calendar Table as per below function:

```
Private Function FillDates()
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim ssql As String
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Records As Integer
    ssql = "SELECT RoomAvailabilityId, Availability FROM RoomAvailability  WHERE Month(AvailabilityDate)=Month(Now()) AND RoomTypesId=1"
    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
    rst.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    rst.Open ssql, cnn
    Records = rst.RecordCount
    For i = 1 To Records
     Me("idtext" & i).Value = rst.Fields!RoomAvailabilityId
     Me("Text" & i).Value = rst.Fields!Availability 
     rst.MoveNext
    Next i
         rst.Close
        Set rst = Nothing
End Function
```

This is a simplified version of the actual code. The actual code hides the text boxes when a month is made up of 30 days or 29/28 days.

So I have 2 values now stored in my grid made up of the above text boxes.

I now want to update my table field called Availability (Number - Long Integer Datatype) with a button click and I am not able to touch base with this.

Could you please suggest how? This is my starting non working code:

```
Private Sub cmdUpdatetxt_Click()
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection '* Connection String
Dim oCm As ADODB.Command '* Command Object
Dim iRecAffected As Integer
Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 31
AvailableRooms = Me("txt" & i).Value
AvailableRoomsId = Me("idtext" & i).Value
Next i
Set oCm = New ADODB.Command
oCm.ActiveConnection = cn
oCm.CommandText = "Update RoomAvailability Set Availability ='" & AvailableRooms & "' WHERE RoomAvailabilityId = '" & AvailableRoomsId & "' AND Month(RoomAvailability.AvailabilityDate) = '" & cboMonthYear.Value & "' "
oCm.Execute iRecAffected
If iRecAffected = 0 Then
MsgBox "Nessun Utente Inserito"
End If
If cn.State <> adStateClosed Then
cn.Close
If Not oCm Is Nothing Then Set oCm = Nothing
If Not cn Is Nothing Then Set cn = Nothing
End If
End Sub
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: You need your SQL in the for next loop, for a start, this will execute the statement 31 times, or you could build the SQL with the 31 text boxes.  From what i can gather you want "update RoomAvailability set availabilty=" & AvailableRooms & " where ........." & AvailableRoomsId, what you have will be box number 31 only.

Comment: Thank you Nathan_Sav, you saved my day. it works. I will made an answer to share the code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per Nathan_Sav suggestion, this is the working code:

```
  Private Sub cmdUpdatetxt_Click()

    On Error GoTo ErrorTrap

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 31
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection '* Connection String
    Dim oCm As ADODB.Command '* Command Object
    Dim iRecAffected As Integer
    Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection
    AvailableRooms = Me("txt" & i).Value
    AvailableRoomsId = Me("idtext" & i).Value
    Set oCm = New ADODB.Command
    oCm.ActiveConnection = cn
    oCm.CommandText = "Update RoomAvailability Set Availability =" & AvailableRooms & " WHERE RoomAvailabilityId = " & AvailableRoomsId & " AND Month(RoomAvailability.AvailabilityDate) = '" & cboMonthYear.Value & "' "
    oCm.Execute iRecAffected
    If iRecAffected = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Nessun Utente Inserito"
    End If
    If cn.State <> adStateClosed Then
    cn.Close
    If Not oCm Is Nothing Then Set oCm = Nothing
    If Not cn Is Nothing Then Set cn = Nothing
    End If
    Next i
    Exit Sub
ErrorTrap:
    MsgBox (Err.Description)
End Sub
```

Have a great day

Comment: I suggest to add exception handler